# Telerik : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oldUpdatePanelIDs' of undefined

Tags: asp.net, telerik

My code was working all Ok but I am suddenly having this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oldUpdatePanelIDs' of undefined
    at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._getPageLoadingEventArgs
```

Its get triggered when I click one of RadTabStrip's Tab.[image]

I have old version of this application where I don't have this error. So I replaced code from old file. But still I am having this error. I searched whole solution in Visual Studio but cannot find 'oldUpdatePanelIDs'. Please help if you have any solution for this.